# How to grab a element on my current tab , which is repeating itself on every tab of my angular page using protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

For example a table is repeating itself on all the 3 tabs of the page with following element.

```
[ng-repeat="(key, r) in $data track by key"]
```

How do i grab the rows of the table on a specific tab.

Using the regular element(by.repeater) .. returns results from all the tabs

Comment: Please  show  HTM code of 2 tabs and include the active tab.  You should find the repeating stuff under the active tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap each tab with an ID and select it via

```
element(<locator of active tab>)
 // find the active tab firstly to tell the next element(by) in the chain:
 // 'your find context is the active tab'

.element(by.repeater(...))
```